# the purpose of the middle part of for loop

Tags: c

```
for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    ++count[str[i]];

// Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual position of
// this character in output array
for (i = 1; i <= RANGE; ++i)
    count[i] += count[i-1];

// Build the output character array
for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
{
    output[count[str[i]]-1] = str[i];
    --count[str[i]];
}
```

Generally the middle part of `for` loop has some comparisons but the first `for` loop here just has an expression. Can you please tell me what that is about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, any expression can be evaluated for 'truth'. In this case, we're checking to see if `str[i]` is true or not. If it is `'\0'`, then it is false and the loop ends - that way we can leave the loop once we find the end of the string. Any other character value is considered true, and the loop continues.

Answer (score 3):

`str[i]` is equivalent to writing `str[i] != 0`

Answer (score 3):

`for` loop takes an expression for the second argument (comparison is also an expression). Expression will yield "true" if the value of it is different than zero.

As you may know, strings in C are terminated by `NUL` character (with the value of `0`), so the

```
for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    ++count[str[i]];
```

really means:

> For each character of the string (from start character - indexed by 0, until the NUL character arrive), increment the appropriate field in the count array.